# Redirect hardcoded program output to stdout?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redirect, stdout

I'm using a program called "prodigal" that does not output to stdout - instead you have to specify an output like so:

```
prodigal -o outfile.txt
```

Instead of going to a specific file I'd like to go stdout - is there a simple way to do this?

So something like this:

```
prodigal -o > stdout
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file system may have an entry for the current process's standard output.

```
prodigal -o /dev/stdout
```

`/dev/stdout` is often a link to an operating-system-specific file, such as `/dev/fd/1` or `/proc/self/fd/1`. I suspect that most Linux distributions will have `/dev/stdout`, or at the very least `/proc/self/fd/1`.

Comment: Sorry, I owe an upvote to you, since my daily limit got exhausted. I will release this upvote tomorrow morning.

Comment: `/dev/stdout` is only treated specially when bash opens it, such as in redirections. Passing `/dev/stdout` to a command requires that there is a file system entry.